# fswin.node:1:2 - Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:2)

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, webpack-5

I am upgrading my Electron app from Angular 11 to Angular 12. I have only a few errors left to handle, one of them being this one.

I am on macOS and `lulop` is an internal dependency that relies on `fswin` on Windows. Is there a way to exclude this module completely on macOS? I am not sure if this must be done through the `package.json` of my Electron app or `lulop`, or even the `webpack.config.js`. Any help is highly appreciated!

```
./src/@external/lulop/node_modules/fswin/electron/ia32/fswin.node:1:2 - Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```